# Word 2013: Suppress Line Numbers VBA

Tags: vba, ms-word, word-2013

I am stuck.

At my organization, we need to check if line numbers are active for a given paragraph. We are attempting to do this but are running into an issue with suppressed line numbers.

We have tried:

```
Selection.Information(wdFirstCharacterLineNumber)
```

and

```
Paragraph.Range.PageSetup.LineNumbers.Active = True
```

However, the paragraph(s) we are trying to avoid have suppressed line numbers. We are trying to determine whether or not the current paragraph has line numbers.

If line numbers are suppressed `LineNumbers.Active` returns `True` for the current paragraph. In addition, if line numbers are suppressed then `wdFirstCharacterLineNumber` returns `1` for the first paragraph even though it is obviously not `1` as I see `1` in a lower paragraph.

I have not found a function that returns a bool or an integer if line numbers are suppressed for a given paragraph.

I welcome any suggestions. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Line numbers are valid for the entire document, which is why what you've tried is returning the information it is.

Line number suppression is direct formatting applied to individual paragraphs, so you need to query the *paragraph* properties. For example:

```
If Selection.Paragraphs(1).NoLineNumber Then
  'True (-1) means the line numbers are suppressed
Else
  'Flase (0) means the line numbers are visible
End If
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I knew there had to be something this simple but could not find any information. Guess I should've browsed all the methods on the paragraph type first. One question though, aren't line numbers valid for the section? If there is a section break, line numbers can be turned off for that section and therefore wouldn't be active for the entire document. Thanks again :-)

Comment: I don't ever use these, just know what they are and where to find it. I did specifically look for whether document or section yesterday, when writing up my answer, and the dialog box didn't *look* like I could specify by section, only renumber by section (or page). So I could be wrong about that :-) Tell me where you find the option and I'll edit my answer...

Comment: Scenario: 3 paragraphs separated by section breaks. If I put my cursor in the middle paragraph, then go to Page Layout > Line Numbers > Line Numbering Options > Line Numbers... (at the bottom) > Check "Add line numbering" and select "Restart each section". If I run a loop through my documents paragraphs, para.range.pagesetup.linenumbering.active is false until I hit my middle paragraph, however, the Selection.Information route returns 1 for the first paragraph which has no line numbers which means that returns the line number count in the actual document. Thanks again for your help :-)